# Python tkinter kept saying my variable to hold the .get() value is not defined

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter, python-3.11

I am learning how to use the .get() for tkinter, and trying to write this basic GUI that can store, process, and display data depending on a user input.

Now (I am fairly new to this, so I am probably wrong) to my knowledge, I need to use the .get() and store it into a variable for future uses.

Now here are my codes, but when I run the code, it kept saying I did not define my variable in the function I defined.

I wrote in Pycharm, the variable I wrote in the first line of the function just keep turning grey.

Why is this happening, am I missing something important?

Sidenote:

I have done some research and saw some result regarding using the following method:

1. StringVar()
2. fstring, f"{}"

but I still can't figure out how that works and how it is affecting my code that Python is not accepting my variable.

```py
Import tkinter as tk

def event():
    expEntry = entry.get()

window = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(window)
button = tk.Button(window,commnad=event())
expEntry = tk.Label(window,text = expEntry)

entry.pack()
button.pack()
expEntry.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `StringVar` to store the value of the entry when `event()` is called by `button`

```
import tkinter as tk


def event():  # use this function to update the StringVar
    entry_content = entry.get()
    entry_var.set(entry_content)


window = tk.Tk()
# declare a StringVar to store the value of your Entry and update your Label
entry_var = tk.StringVar(window, 'Default Text')
# use 'textvariable' here to update the label when the bound variable changes
expEntry = tk.Label(window, textvariable=entry_var)
entry = tk.Entry(window)
# there was a typo in 'command' here, FIY
button = tk.Button(window, text='Press me', command=event)  

entry.pack()
button.pack()
expEntry.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Note: you don't need the `()` for the command binding, as you're not calling the `event` function there! You're just telling the `button` the name of the function it should call.

Comment: The first paragraph in your answer is wrong.  In OP code, `entry` is defined and it is a global variable before `event()` is executed, so it can be accessed inside `event()`.  What I get is `NameError: name 'expEntry' is not defined` at the line `expEntry = tk.Label(window,text = expEntry)` when running OP code (after fixing some typo errors).

Comment: Fair, I'll update

Comment: `Import tkinter as tk` should be `import tkinter as tk`.

Comment: Fixed - good catch

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do this. Just added `tk.StringVar()`.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("700x300")
window.title("StringVar Object in Entry Widget")
var =tk.StringVar(window)

def event():   
   Label2.config(text=var.get())

myEntry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=var)
myEntry.pack()

myButton = tk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=event)
myButton.pack()

Label2 = tk.Label(window, font="Calibri,10")
Label2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Output before:

[image]

Output after:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for the solution, I tried to use your method into my code, but it just kept saying Label2 is not defined.

Comment: Which line number getting an error? I tried it against and it worked.